# how to filter array with date?

Tags: php, arrays, filter

I need to delete any where 'Vencimiento' is different from the current month

I have this array which can be variable, so it occurs to me that I must be a foreach and search if the first 6 characters of expiration ("2017-11" -xx) are equal to the current month verifying it with date ()

ARRAY:

```
 array(2) {
  [264]=>
  array(10) {
    [0]=>
    array(6) {
      ["idImpuesto"]=>
      int(10)
      ["idConcepto"]=>
      int(19)
      ["periodo"]=>
      string(4) "2017"
      ["tipoOperacion"]=>
      string(12) "PRESENTACION"
      ["vencimiento"]=>
      string(10) "2017-11-13"
      ["formularios"]=>
      string(3) "713"
    }
    [1]=>                               //DELETE
    array(6) {
      ["idImpuesto"]=>                    
      int(10)
      ["idConcepto"]=>
      int(19)
      ["periodo"]=>
      string(4) "2017"
      ["tipoOperacion"]=>
      string(12) "PRESENTACION"
      ["vencimiento"]=>
      string(10) "2017-12-29"                  //IT'S NOT THE CURRENT MONTH
      ["formularios"]=>
      string(3) "713"
    }
    [2]=>                                       //DELETE
    array(5) {
      ["idImpuesto"]=>
      int(10)
      ["idConcepto"]=>
      int(859)
      ["periodo"]=>
      string(4) "2017"
      ["tipoOperacion"]=>
      string(12) "PRESENTACION"
      ["vencimiento"]=>
      string(10) "2017-12-13"                //IT'S NOT THE CURRENT MONTH
    }
    [3]=>
    array(5) {
      ["idImpuesto"]=>
      int(10)
      ["idConcepto"]=>
      int(19)
      ["periodo"]=>
      string(4) "2017"
      ["tipoOperacion"]=>
      string(4) "PAGO"
      ["vencimiento"]=>
      string(10) "2017-11-13"
    }
    [4]=>                                         //DELETE
    array(6) {
      ["idImpuesto"]=>
      int(10)
      ["idConcepto"]=>
      int(191)
      ["periodo"]=>
      string(4) "2018"
      ["anticipoCuota"]=>
      int(1)
      ["tipoOperacion"]=>
      string(4) "PAGO"
      ["vencimiento"]=>
      string(10) "2017-12-13"                   //IT'S NOT THE CURRENT MONTH
    }
    [5]=>                                       //DELETE
    array(6) {
      ["idImpuesto"]=>
      int(10)
      ["idConcepto"]=>
      int(191)
      ["periodo"]=>
      string(4) "2018"
      ["anticipoCuota"]=>
      int(2)
      ["tipoOperacion"]=>
      string(4) "PAGO"
      ["vencimiento"]=>
      string(10) "2018-01-15"                   //IT'S NOT THE CURRENT MONTH
    }
    [6]=>                                     //DELETE
    array(5) {
      ["idImpuesto"]=>
      int(10)
      ["idConcepto"]=>
      int(859)
      ["periodo"]=>
      string(4) "2017"
      ["tipoOperacion"]=>
      string(4) "PAGO"
      ["vencimiento"]=>
      string(10) "2017-12-13"                  //IT'S NOT THE CURRENT MONTH
    }
    [7]=>                                      //DELETE
    array(6) {
      ["idImpuesto"]=>
      int(30)
      ["idConcepto"]=>
      int(19)
      ["periodo"]=>
      string(7) "2017-12"
      ["tipoOperacion"]=>
      string(12) "PRESENTACION"
      ["vencimiento"]=>
      string(10) "2018-01-18"                   //IT'S NOT THE CURRENT MONTH
      ["formularios"]=>
      string(8) "731,2002"
    }
    [8]=>                                      //DELETE
    array(6) {
      ["idImpuesto"]=>
      int(30)
      ["idConcepto"]=>
      int(19)
      ["periodo"]=>
      string(7) "2017-11"
      ["tipoOperacion"]=>
      string(12) "PRESENTACION"
      ["vencimiento"]=>
      string(10) "2017-12-18"                 //IT'S NOT THE CURRENT MONTH
      ["formularios"]=>
      string(8) "731,2002"
    }
    [9]=>                                        
    array(6) {
      ["idImpuesto"]=>
      int(30)
      ["idConcepto"]=>
      int(19)
      ["periodo"]=>
      string(7) "2017-10"
      ["tipoOperacion"]=>
      string(12) "PRESENTACION"
      ["vencimiento"]=>
      string(10) "2017-11-21"
      ["formularios"]=>
      string(8) "731,2002"
    }
  }
  [265]=>
  array(9) {
    [0]=>                                 //DELETE
    array(6) {
      ["idImpuesto"]=>
      int(11)
      ["idConcepto"]=>
      int(191)
      ["periodo"]=>
      string(4) "2017"
      ["anticipoCuota"]=>
      int(4)
      ["tipoOperacion"]=>
      string(4) "PAGO"
      ["vencimiento"]=>
      string(10) "2017-12-13"                 //IT'S NOT THE CURRENT MONTH
    }
    [1]=>                                  //DELETE
    array(6) {
      ["idImpuesto"]=>
      int(30)
      ["idConcepto"]=>
      int(19)
      ["periodo"]=>
      string(7) "2017-12"
      ["tipoOperacion"]=>
      string(12) "PRESENTACION"
      ["vencimiento"]=>
      string(10) "2018-01-18"                  //IT'S NOT THE CURRENT MONTH
      ["formularios"]=>
      string(8) "731,2002"
    }
    [2]=>                                  //DELETE
    array(6) {
      ["idImpuesto"]=>
      int(30)
      ["idConcepto"]=>
      int(19)
      ["periodo"]=>
      string(7) "2017-11"
      ["tipoOperacion"]=>
      string(12) "PRESENTACION"
      ["vencimiento"]=>
      string(10) "2017-12-19"                  //IT'S NOT THE CURRENT MONTH
      ["formularios"]=>
      string(8) "731,2002"
    }
    [3]=>
    array(6) {
      ["idImpuesto"]=>
      int(30)
      ["idConcepto"]=>
      int(19)
      ["periodo"]=>
      string(7) "2017-10"
      ["tipoOperacion"]=>
      string(12) "PRESENTACION"
      ["vencimiento"]=>
      string(10) "2017-11-22"
      ["formularios"]=>
      string(8) "731,2002"
    }
    [4]=>                                     //DELETE
    array(5) {
      ["idImpuesto"]=>
      int(30)
      ["idConcepto"]=>
      int(19)
      ["periodo"]=>
      string(7) "2017-12"
      ["tipoOperacion"]=>
      string(4) "PAGO"
      ["vencimiento"]=>
      string(10) "2018-01-18"                   //IT'S NOT THE CURRENT MONTH
    }
    [5]=>                                       //DELETE
    array(5) {
      ["idImpuesto"]=>
      int(30)
      ["idConcepto"]=>
      int(19)
      ["periodo"]=>
      string(7) "2017-11"
      ["tipoOperacion"]=>
      string(4) "PAGO"
      ["vencimiento"]=>
      string(10) "2017-12-19"                 //IT'S NOT THE CURRENT MONTH
    }
    [6]=>
    array(5) {
      ["idImpuesto"]=>
      int(30)
      ["idConcepto"]=>
      int(19)
      ["periodo"]=>
      string(7) "2017-10"
      ["tipoOperacion"]=>
      string(4) "PAGO"
      ["vencimiento"]=>
      string(10) "2017-11-22"
    }
    [7]=>                                   //DELETE
    array(5) {
      ["idImpuesto"]=>
      int(308)
      ["idConcepto"]=>
      int(19)
      ["periodo"]=>
      string(7) "2017-11"
      ["tipoOperacion"]=>
      string(4) "PAGO"
      ["vencimiento"]=>
      string(10) "2017-12-05"                  //IT'S NOT THE CURRENT MONTH
    }
    [8]=>
    array(5) {
      ["idImpuesto"]=>
      int(308)
      ["idConcepto"]=>
      int(19)
      ["periodo"]=>
      string(7) "2017-10"
      ["tipoOperacion"]=>
      string(4) "PAGO"
      ["vencimiento"]=>
      string(10) "2017-11-06"
    }
  }
}
```

How can I filter the entire array in this way?

```
array(2) {
      [264]=>
      array(24) {
        [0]=>
        array(6) {
          ["idImpuesto"]=>
          int(10)
          ["idConcepto"]=>
          int(19)
          ["periodo"]=>
          string(4) "2017"
          ["tipoOperacion"]=>
          string(12) "PRESENTACION"
          ["vencimiento"]=>
          string(10) "2017-11-13"
          ["formularios"]=>
          string(3) "713"
        }
        [1]=>
        array(5) {
          ["idImpuesto"]=>
          int(10)
          ["idConcepto"]=>
          int(19)
          ["periodo"]=>
          string(4) "2017"
          ["tipoOperacion"]=>
          string(4) "PAGO"
          ["vencimiento"]=>
          string(10) "2017-11-13"
        }
        [2]=>                                        
        array(6) {
          ["idImpuesto"]=>
          int(30)
          ["idConcepto"]=>
          int(19)
          ["periodo"]=>
          string(7) "2017-10"
          ["tipoOperacion"]=>
          string(12) "PRESENTACION"
          ["vencimiento"]=>
          string(10) "2017-11-21"
          ["formularios"]=>
          string(8) "731,2002"
        }
        [3]=>
        array(5) {
          ["idImpuesto"]=>
          int(30)
          ["idConcepto"]=>
          int(19)
          ["periodo"]=>
          string(7) "2017-10"
          ["tipoOperacion"]=>
          string(4) "PAGO"
          ["vencimiento"]=>
          string(10) "2017-11-21"
        }
      }
      [265]=>
      array(3) {
        [0]=>
        array(6) {
          ["idImpuesto"]=>
          int(30)
          ["idConcepto"]=>
          int(19)
          ["periodo"]=>
          string(7) "2017-10"
          ["tipoOperacion"]=>
          string(12) "PRESENTACION"
          ["vencimiento"]=>
          string(10) "2017-11-22"
          ["formularios"]=>
          string(8) "731,2002"
        }
        [1]=>
        array(5) {
          ["idImpuesto"]=>
          int(30)
          ["idConcepto"]=>
          int(19)
          ["periodo"]=>
          string(7) "2017-10"
          ["tipoOperacion"]=>
          string(4) "PAGO"
          ["vencimiento"]=>
          string(10) "2017-11-22"
        }
        [2]=>
        array(5) {
          ["idImpuesto"]=>
          int(308)
          ["idConcepto"]=>
          int(19)
          ["periodo"]=>
          string(7) "2017-10"
          ["tipoOperacion"]=>
          string(4) "PAGO"
          ["vencimiento"]=>
          string(10) "2017-11-06"
        }
      }
    }
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code creates a new array with desired output.

```
// define new array
$new_array = array();
// get year and date in the same format as vencimiento in array
$year_month = date('Y-m');
foreach($array as $key=>$value){
    foreach($value as $k=>$v){
        // check for the condition
        if(substr($v['vencimiento'], 0, 7) == $year_month){
            // assign to new array
            $new_array[$key][]=$v;  
        }
    }
}
print_r($new_array);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use two loops and `date()` to compare just the year and month:

```
foreach($array as &$val1) {
    foreach($val1 as &$val2) {
        if(date('Y-m', strtotime($val2['vencimiento'])) != date('Y-m')) {
            unset($val2);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One could use `date()` to get the current month name and then put them into a new array like:

```
$result = [];
foreach($var as $v) {
    foreach($v as $a) {


        $date = date('F',strtotime($a['vencimiento']));
        $now = date('F');

        if($date === $now) {
            $result[] = $v;
        }
    }
}

var_dump($var);
var_dump($result);
```

https://3v4l.org/15PK3

Answer (score 0):

[array_filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) is your friend.

Assuming your full array is `$array`:

```
$current_month = date('Y-m');
foreach($array as $key => $sub_array) {
    $array[$key] = array_filter($sub_array, function($item) use($current_month) {
        return substr($item['vencimiento'], 0, 7) == $current_month;
    });
}

$array = array_filter($array);
```